# Can I nominate my own shorthand name for frequently used types in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, types

For example, if I consider a **record** to be a `Dictionary(of String, String)`, and I consider a **record set** to by `List(of Dictionary(of String, String))`, it gets pretty ugly to have to continually use these type definitions.

What I'd like to do in VB.NET is to nominate a name to this sort of type. So for example instead of the following code:

```
private sub processRecordList(recList as List(of Dictionary(of String, String)))
    dim myNewRecord as Dictionary(of String, String)
end sub
```

I could just use:

```
private sub processRecordList(recSet as RecordSetType)
    dim myNewRecord as RecordType
end sub
```

I think this would be a lot cleaner, but is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want to change the name? You are just obfuscating the type, making it harder for programmers who come after you to follow your code.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 You wouldn't want write the full definition of a class or a structure where-ever you need to refer to it as a type. That's what the definition is for. I don't see that this is any different just because I've built my "class" out of nested generics. Obfuscation is in the eye of the beholder, perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work or not, but have you considered creating a new class that simply inherits from your more complex class?

```
Public Class MyComplexClass
    Inherits List(of Dictionary(of String, String))

End Class
```

Comment: This also works, and may in fact be a cleaner solution than @Styxxy's solution. For example I can explicitly say that RecordSetType Inherits `List(Of RecordType)`, whereas the "Imports" solution forces me to spell out `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String))`

Answer (score 3):

You can [`Import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx) using an alias

```
Imports IntList = System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)

Dim mylist As New IntList()
' is equal to
Dim mylist As New List(Of Integer)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works! It's a bit ugly to have to use the fully qualified names of the types, but it will save a lot of ugliness later on.

Comment: Sorry I can't nominate two "accepted answers" even though yours is perfectly correct.